# rails .each is skipping the second element through for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreach, each

I have the following code:

```
@referred_emails = Array.new
@referred_emails = params.select{|k, v| k.start_with?('referred_') }.values

puts "referred emails array: " + @referred_emails.inspect.to_s

@referred_emails.each_with_index do |referred_email, index|
    puts "index is #{index}.  referred_email is #{referred_email}"
end
```

Here is the serve log:

```
15:25:34 web.1  | referred emails array: ["theiremail1", "theiremail2", "theiremail3"]
15:25:34 web.1  | index is 0.  referred_email is theiremail1
15:25:35 web.1  | index is 1.  referred_email is theiremail3
```

As you can see, for some reason the second element in the array is being skipped.  It should output the following:

```
15:25:34 web.1  | referred emails array: ["theiremail1", "theiremail2", "theiremail3"]
15:25:34 web.1  | index is 0.  referred_email is theiremail1
15:25:34 web.1  | index is 1.  referred_email is theiremail2
15:25:35 web.1  | index is 2.  referred_email is theiremail3
```

but for some reason it keeps skipping the second 1.

Here are the parameters:

```
15:25:34 web.1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"f7f0idqcQpXG/XzhQYCaEj3xQHLiQz1Nf1z9gF3CMxM=", 
    "referrer_email"=>"", "referrer_name"=>"", "referred_0"=>"theiremail1", 
    "referred_1"=>"theiremail2", "referred_2"=>"theiremail3", "commit"=>"SUBMIT"}
```

Why is it skipping the second element?

Comment: Could you show us the exact code ?

Comment: what do you mean?  I did...

Comment: The filtering you do is more commonly done with [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

Comment: Show us what is being passed in `params`. Your code is a little messy, but it should be working just fine.

Comment: Rob Wagner, I put up the params.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not doing any other operation on `@referred_emails` after getting it assigned by `select` method?

Comment: Are you using threads? Perhaps you have concurrency and another processor is doing something with the second entry?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong at your end but, everything seems to work for me at least:

```
params = {"referrer_email"=>"", "referrer_name"=>"", "referred_0"=>"theiremail1", "referred_1"=>"theiremail2", "referred_2"=>"theiremail3"}
params.select{|k, v| k.include?('referred_') }.values
#=> ["theiremail1", "theiremail2", "theiremail3"]
```

or:

```
params.select{|k, v| k.start_with?('referred_') }.values
#=> ["theiremail1", "theiremail2", "theiremail3"]
```

or:

```
params.select{|k, v| k.include?('referred_') }.
       each_with_index{|(k, v), i| puts "index is #{i}. referred_email is #{v}" } 
#=> index is 0. referred_email is theiremail1
#=> index is 1. referred_email is theiremail2
#=> index is 2. referred_email is theiremail3
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not having problems creating the right array.  The array is created properly (although i do like your code better), but when i loop through it the loop skips the second one.  I tried it with your 2nd code block and it still isn't working.

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure that I haven't hardcoded the output I posted in my answer, it was generated and puked by my irb. Can you try the same in your irb or rails console? :)

Comment: @Philip7899 I believe what Surya is saying is that you haven't given us enough information to reproduce the problem. And if we can't reproduce the problem, we can't fix it (since from our perspective, there is no problem to fix in the first place).

Comment: Weird, I tried it in the console and got: 'NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for #<Hash:0x007fdd395b4140>' after i ran the select method, which is weird, because I changed my actual code to reflect your second code block, and it works there.

Comment: @Ajedi32, I understand what you're saying, but I've uploaded literally all the code there is.  i don't have any other code in the controller to upload.  I've written hundreds of .each loops before, but I don't have the slightest clue what is causing this problem.  I agree, I can't see what could be causing the error - which is why i stack overflowed it.

Comment: OK, what did you do to produce that error? just launched console and ran commands I posted? Which version of Ruby are you using? Maybe try to restart/relaunch your irb or rails console and then try?

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code you provided. If I paste the following output into a blank file named `test.rb`:

```
params = {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"f7f0idqcQpXG/XzhQYCaEj3xQHLiQz1Nf1z9gF3CMxM=", 
  "referrer_email"=>"",
  "referrer_name"=>"",
  "referred_0"=>"theiremail1", 
  "referred_1"=>"theiremail2",
  "referred_2"=>"theiremail3",
  "commit"=>"SUBMIT"
}

@referred_emails = Array.new
@referred_emails = params.select{|k, v| k.start_with?('referred_') }.values

puts "referred emails array: " + @referred_emails.inspect.to_s

@referred_emails.each_with_index do |referred_email, index|
    puts "index is #{index}.  referred_email is #{referred_email}"
end
```

...and I then run `ruby test.rb`, I get the following output on Ruby 2.0+:

```
referred emails array: ["theiremail1", "theiremail2", "theiremail3"]
index is 0.  referred_email is theiremail1
index is 1.  referred_email is theiremail2
index is 2.  referred_email is theiremail3
```

If there is a bug in your code, it's not in the code sample you provided.